# how can i handle errors and continue function ? Javascript js

Tags: javascript

```js
function mix(){
    //console.log(arguments)
    let answer;
    let errorsArr=[];
    let errorNew;
    iterations: for( let i = 0 ; i < arguments.length; i++){
        if(typeof arguments[i]!=='function'){
            throw new Error('Every argument has to be function!')
        }else{
                try {
                    answer = arguments[i](answer); 
                    
                } catch (error) {
                    errorNew = {name:`${error.name}`,message : `${error.message}`,stack:`${error.stack}`,level:`${error.level}`}
                    errorsArr.push(errorNew)
                   
                } finally{
                    continue iterations;
                }

        }
    }
    const returnedObject = {
        errors :errorsArr,
        value: answer
    }

    return returnedObject;
    
}


function square(n){
    return n*2
}
function million(){
    return  1000000
}
function divideTwo(n){
    return n/2;
}


console.log(mix(million,square,divideTwo))
```

I had a homework to do a mix function to an unlimited arguments. it works perfectly if all arguments are functions but when any kind of error occurs it should handle and skip errored iteration without breaking program. how can I handle it correctly?

Comment: As a small tip, you only need the `iterations` label if you need to continue from within a nested loop. `continue` will work fine on its own in a single loop. You're also throwing the "not a function" exception before you enter your `try` block, meaning that those exceptions won't get caught or handled by your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just catch `throw new Error('Every argument has to be function!')`

```js
function mix(){
    //console.log(arguments)
    let answer;
    let errorsArr=[];
    let errorNew;
    iterations: for( let i = 0 ; i < arguments.length; i++){
        if(typeof arguments[i]!=='function'){
         try {
            throw new Error('Every argument has to be function!')
              } catch (error) {
                    errorNew = {name:`${error.name}`,message : `${error.message}`,stack:`${error.stack}`,level:`${error.level}`}
                    errorsArr.push(errorNew)
                   
                }
        }else{
               
                    answer = arguments[i](answer); 
                    
        

        }
    }
    const returnedObject = {
        errors :errorsArr,
        value: answer
    }

    return returnedObject;
    
}


function square(n){
    return n*2
}
function million(){
    return  1000000
}
function divideTwo(n){
    return n/2;
}


console.log(mix(million,square,divideTwo, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Its the issue with your error handling section.

You should wrap your `typeof arguments[i] !== "function"` statement inside a `try catch` because its that place where you are throwing the error

```js
function mix() {
  console.log(arguments);
  let answer;
  let errorsArr = [];
  let errorNew;
  iterations: for (let i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    try {
      if (typeof arguments[i] !== "function") {
        throw new Error("Every argument has to be function!");
      } else {
        answer = arguments[i](answer);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      errorNew = {
        name: `${error.name}`,
        message: `${error.message}`,
        stack: `${error.stack}`,
        level: `${error.level}`,
      };
      errorsArr.push(errorNew);
      continue iterations;
    }
  }
  const returnedObject = {
    errors: errorsArr,
    value: answer,
  };

  return returnedObject;
}

function square(n) {
  return n * 2;
}
function million() {
  return 1000000;
}
function divideTwo(n) {
  return n / 2;
}

console.log(mix(million, 5, square, divideTwo));
```